# How to access a Realm instance in the same thread that it was created in .NET (Xamarin-UWP)?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, realm, synchronizationcontext

I am working on the migration from SQLite/WebApis to **Realms** in an App in Xamarin Forms.

This application manages a **messaging service** (Chat through SignalR).

The problem that has arisen is when a message is received, which I try to store in a database, the application crashes unexpectedly. (Question that did not happen with SQLite).

I am getting the famous error: **realm accessed from incorrect**, exactly when the 3rd or 4th message is trying to insert, it has been a bit difficult to see the precise moment.

As I could read, both in questions right here on Stackoverflow, and on the Dot-Net Realm GitHub. the instance must be accessed in the same thread that it was created.

As they suggest, one way to achieve this is by using the correct **SynchronizationContext** through `AsyncContext.Run` **Nito.AsyncEx by Stephen Cleary** or `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`.

I ask the question because unfortunately, I handle the subject of threads and tasks at a basic level, in what way do I have to approach the previous suggestions to my code? or what should I set correctly to access the thread in which it was created?

This is my code:

```
LobbyViewModel
public LobbyViewModel()
{
     ChatService.OnReceivePrivateMessage += ChatService_OnReceivePrivateMessage;
}

private async void ChatService_OnReceivePrivateMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs args)
{
    await SendMessage(…);
}

private async Task SendMessage(…)
{
    await UpdateMetaData(…);
}

public async Task UpdateMetaData(…)
{
    await ManagerService.InsertMetaDataChatAsync(metaDataChat);
}

ManagerService
public async Task InsertMetaDataChatAsync (MetaDataChatModel MetaDataChatModel)
{

    IMetaDataChatServices MetaDataChatServices = App.AppContainer.Resolve<IMetaDataChatServices>();

    IResponse DataResult = (await MetaDataChatServices.Insert(MetaDataChatModel));

}

Repository
public async Task<IResponse> CreateAsync(MetaDataChatModel MetaDataChatModel)
        {
            MetaDataChatModel.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            MetaDataChatModel.Partition = _realmManager.projectPartition;

            var MetaDataChatDto = MetaDataChatModel.ToDto();

            var realmInstance = await _realmManager.GetInstanceAsync();
            if (realmInstance == null)
                return new Response(false, "Realm instance can't be null");

            await realmInstance.WriteAsync(realm =>
            {
                realm.Add(MetaDataChatDto, false);
            });

            return new Response(true);
        }
        
RealmManager
public RealmManager()
{
    RealmApp = App.Create(appId);
    //DataBase = Realms.Realm.GetInstance(syncConfig);
}

public Task<Realms.Realm> GetInstanceAsync()
{
    return Realms.Realm.GetInstanceAsync(syncConfig);
}

public async Task RealmLogInAsync()
{
    if (RealmApp.CurrentUser == null)
    {
        User user = await RealmApp.
        LogInAsync(Credentials.EmailPassword("email", "password"));

        if (user == null)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    projectPartition = $"project={RealmApp.CurrentUser.Id}";
    syncConfig = new SyncConfiguration(projectPartition, RealmApp.CurrentUser);
}

public async Task RealmLogOutAsync()
{
    if (RealmApp != null && RealmApp.CurrentUser!=null)
    {
        await RealmApp.CurrentUser?.LogOutAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ivanrlg your code is slightly confusing. Can you highlight in your code snippet at which point you get the exception?

Comment: HI @papafe I try to clean it up a bit. the exception occurs here: `public async Task <IResponse> CreateAsync (MetaDataChatModel MetaDataChatModel)`. I think that at some point it has not finished inserting when another thread is inserting too and there crash.

Comment: @ Ivanrlg just to be sure, in `CreateAsync`, you have `realm.Add(MetaDataChatDto)`. Is it actually `realmInstance.Add(MetaDataChatDto)` or am I missing something?

Comment: Hello @papafe, it's realm.Add(MetaDataChatDto, false);. use realm inside. referred from here:
[link]https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-legacy/docs/dotnet/latest/api/reference/Realms.Realm.html#Realms_Realm_WriteAsync_System_Action_Realms_Realm__

Comment: ah yes, I am sorry, I misread, my bad! :)